# Ear deploy failed if Myfaces installed as module on Widlfy

Tags: jsf, wildfly, web-deployment, ear, myfaces

I have installed myfaces 2.3.6 as module in Wildfly 19.1.0 as described [here](https://docs.wildfly.org/19/Admin_Guide.html#JSF). If I check with jboss-cli the default myfaces impl I get the right one (2.3.6).

- If I deploy a war file everything is ok.
- If I deploy the "same" war file integrated in a ear something goes wrong and I'm getting strange Exceptions that some of my Web classes (included in .\WEB-INF\classes) are not found:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mycompany.MyBeanClass
>   from [Module \"com.sun.jsf-impl:myfaces-2.3.6\" version 2.3.6 from
>   local module loader ...]

The exactly same ear with integrated myfaces libs and special param org.jboss.jbossfaces.WAR_BUNDLES_JSF_IMPL set in web.xml works as expected.

I'm missing something? Should I change jboss-deployment-structure.xml or MANIFEST File?

---

Additional info
.\com\sun\jsf-impl\myfaces-2.3.6\module.xml

```
 <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.8" name="com.sun.jsf-impl:myfaces-2.3.6">
    <properties>
        <property name="jboss.api" value="private"/>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.faces.api:myfaces-2.3.6">
            <imports>
                <include path="META-INF/**"/>
            </imports>
        </module>
        <module name="javax.annotation.api"/>
        <module name="javax.servlet.api"/>
        <module name="javax.servlet.jsp.api"/>
        <module name="javax.websocket.api" />
        <module name="javax.validation.api"/>
        <module name="javax.json.api"/>
        <module name="javax.ejb.api"/>
        <module name="javax.xml.bind.api"/>
        <module name="org.glassfish.jakarta.el"/>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.servlet.jstl.api"/>
        <module name="org.apache.xerces" services="import"/>
        <module name="org.apache.xalan" services="import"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.weld.core"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.weld.spi"/>

        <!-- extra dependencies for MyFaces -->
        <module name="org.apache.commons.collections"/>
        <module name="org.apache.commons.codec"/>
        <module name="org.apache.commons.beanutils"/>
        <module name="org.apache.commons.digester"/>
    </dependencies>

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="myfaces-impl-2.3.6.jar"/>
    </resources>
</module>
```

.\javax\faces\api\myfaces-2.3.6\module.xml

```
   <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.8" name="javax.faces.api:myfaces-2.3.6">
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.enterprise.api" export="true"/>
        <module name="javax.servlet.api" export="true"/>
        <module name="javax.servlet.jsp.api" export="true"/>
        <module name="javax.servlet.jstl.api" export="true"/>
        <module name="javax.validation.api" export="true"/>
        <module name="org.glassfish.jakarta.el" export="true"/>
        <module name="javax.api"/>

        <!-- extra dependencies for MyFaces 1.1
        <module name="org.apache.commons.logging"/>
        <module name="org.apache.commons.el"/>
        <module name="org.apache.commons.lang"/> -->
    </dependencies>

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="myfaces-api-2.3.6.jar"/>
    </resources>
</module>
```

.\org\jboss\as\jsf-injection\myfaces-2.3.6\module.xml

```
 <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.5" name="org.jboss.as.jsf-injection" slot="myfaces-2.3.6">
    <properties>
        <property name="jboss.api" value="private"/>
    </properties>

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="wildfly-jsf-injection-19.1.0.Final.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="weld-jsf-3.1.3.Final.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="myfaces-2.3.6"/>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.as.web-common"/>
        <module name="javax.servlet.api"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.as.ee"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.as.jsf"/>


        <module name="javax.enterprise.api"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.weld.core"/>
        <module name="org.wildfly.security.elytron"/>


        <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="myfaces-2.3.6"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

MANIFEST File (in ear and war)

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.10.5
Created-By: 11.0.6+10-LTS (Azul Systems, Inc.)
```

jboss-deployment-structure.xml (in ear and war)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.1">
  <deployment>
    <dependencies>
    <module name="org.jboss.remote-naming" export="true" />

    <module name="org.infinispan.core" slot="ispn-9.4" services="export" export="true"/>
    <module name="org.infinispan.commons" slot="ispn-9.4" services="export" export="true"/>
    <module name="org.infinispan" slot="ispn-9.4" services="export" export="true"/>

    <module name="org.jboss.xnio" export="true" />
    <module name="org.jboss.remoting3" export="true" />
    <module name="org.apache.cxf"/>
        <module name="org.apache.cxf.impl"/>
    </dependencies>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

web.xml

```
...
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.jboss.jbossfaces.JSF_CONFIG_NAME</param-name>
    <param-value>myfaces-2.3.6</param-value>
</context-param>
...
```

Comment: What if you not make it the default but do that via web.xml like in the link you posted: `<context-param>
  <param-name>org.jboss.jbossfaces.JSF_CONFIG_NAME</param-name>
  <param-value>myfaces-2.2.12</param-value>
</context-param>`

Comment: Same error (the "not found class" is not always the same)

Comment: But always a class that is in the war in the ear? Can you post the module.xml you use in the question so instead of just referring to the link, post _**YOUR**_ actual config. And what if you try a newer mojarra (2.3.13 e.g.) Same problem?

Comment: And why did you remove this question by you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58299332/cannot-deploy-ear-file-to-wildfly-using-myfaces

Comment: Oh and `"com.sun.jsf-impl:myfaces-2.3.6\`  is weird... Might just be a 'reference' but feels weird. And regarding the jboss-deployment-structure.xml, try... and you know

Comment: I have posted the two module.xml. And yes, the Class not found always refer to a class in the war (in the ear). I'm using myfaces and 2.3.6 is the newer version

Comment: No the 'prefix' "com.sun.jsf-impl" is weird... Has nothing to do with myfaces. And it even contradicts the module name in the module.xml... So this combination is strange

Comment: Hmmm the `com.sun.jsf-impl` is in 'myfaces template' in the https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/master/jsf/multi-jsf-installer/src/main/resources/myfaces-impl-module.xml, ok just something that 'looks' weird then. And can you add the module tag around the first file? And do you have a properties element in there?

Comment: Did you add the other modules too? injection, digester? https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/tree/master/jsf/multi-jsf-installer/src/main/resources

Comment: Yes, other modules are added too. I have provided the module.xml for injection. And I have formatted the code for the other two, the <module> tag was cut by code formatter

Comment: Could it be you have some left-overs from the ear/war with embedded myfaces? Tried running this same ear/war with mojarra?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214886/discussion-between-kukeltje-and-zardo).